# Inject input in reactive form and used validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hello i have a question about Reactive-Form.
I have a parent-form with the common structure of my form.
Some children (input) of the form can be here or not.

What is the best way for this?

i have try with inject the children form with input with new formgroup but now i have validation control (field is invalid but not the form :( ).

this is my testing code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjc8aa

I'm so lost please help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, all that you need to do is to pass the parent as a binding to the child form component and receive the binding in the child as an input.
`<childComponent [parent]=“myForm”></childComponent>`
In the child component: @Input(‘parent’) parent:any
Then you can simply use this.parent.formControl in the child.

Comment: Okay that work but i have another probleme.
**ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.**

in my children component i have define another formGroup.
`<div [formGroup]="ftpGroup">`

and in the TS:
a property
`ftpGroup: FormGroup;`

And in the ngOnInit
`
      this.ftpGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        ftphost: [null, Validators.required]
      });

      this.parent.addControl('ftpGroup', this.ftpGroup);`

The parent is the parent formgroup.

Comment: In you child component, you do not need to create another formGroup.  Simply use the parent formGroup that you've passed in as a binding.  In your external-form-1.component.html, change line 1 to look like this: ```<div [formGroup]="parent" ``` and move the email formControl up to the parent component: ```  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],                                                                    email: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }```

Comment: It does not work I have the same message. :(
Moreover, if I add the controls of my child component in the parent formgroup I can not have validation of my form anymore when the fields of the other components are not displayed.
I'm sorry but im lost from two days with this form from hell

Comment: Clearly I'm not understanding your question.  Why are you using a child component in the form in the first place?  The form that you've shown does not require it.  Is there something that I'm missing?  When I look at your stack blitz, the validation works, but with your form schema the form will never submit properly.

Comment: The stackblitz is not representative of my real form its just for the concept.
My form is a multi choice for configuration.
We can choose 5 différents configurations methods.
But we have just one form with one action API for that.
So my control must be active just for the active tab (part of the form).

Comment: You need to ask concise questions.  It turns out that the question that you've asked is not the question that you want answered?  The idea of constructing a multi choice form requires a different approach than what I've been suggesting to you.  I've created large multi layered multi component forms that have required the use of ngSwitch, parent forms (as described above), event emitters, and the formBuilder API (especially setValue()).  If this is what you are asking, I suggest that you edit your original question.